# How to create custom page to reset password for portal user in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex, reset-password

I use Site.forgotPassword to get a link to reset my password
My Q is : how I  customize the page that I get ?

Here a print screen of the current page that I want to change:

'https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHlNz.jpg'

there is any why to work this done?(google didnt manage to help me..(

10x alot guys

Menashe Yamin